# Event data from rows to columns by ID in R, Reshape?

Tags: r, reshape

I have several thousands of rows of data in this form:

```
a= c("id", "start", "mid1", "mid2", "finish")
b= c("id1", "date1", "date2", "date3",  "date4")
c= c("id2", "date5", "date6", NA, "date7")
d= c("id3", "date8", "date9", "date10", "date11")

df=as.data.frame(rbind(b,c,d))
colnames(df)=a
rownames(df)=c(1:nrow(df))

df

#    id start  mid1   mid2 finish
# 1 id1 date1 date2  date3  date4
# 2 id2 date5 date6   <NA>  date7
# 3 id3 date8 date9 date10 date11
# ...
```

And I would need to have it in this form:

```
id;  event  ;date
id1; start  ;date1
id1; mid1   ;date2
id1; mid2   ;date3
id1; finish ;date4
id2; start  ;date5
id2; mid1   ;date6 
id2; finish ;date7
id3; start  ;date8
id3; mid1   ;date9  
id3; mid2   ;date10  
id3; finish ;date11
...
```

I found this question which was almost the same but the other way around: [How to transform Columns to rows in R?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5251249/how-to-transform-columns-to-rows-in-r)

How could I accomplish the transformation?

Comment: have a look at `reshape2::melt`

Comment: Have a look at `tidyr::gather`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to put `NA` instead of blank in your original data and as said by Davide use `melt`, ignoring `NA` to obtain the result you want:

```
> df
   id start  mid1   mid2 finish
1 id1 date1 date2  date3  date4
2 id2 date5 date6   <NA>  date7
3 id3 date8 date9 date10 date11

library(reshape2)

melt(df, id.vars="id", variable.name="event",value.name="date",na.rm=TRUE)
```

Comment: I added df=df[with(df, order(df$id)),] and now this does it also! Thanks so much! How could i give the green check to you too?

Comment: It's up to you to judge who helped you the most regarding your question!

Answer (score 2):

As mentioned in the comments, you can use `tidyr::gather`.  Here I use it in combination with `dplyr`, and chain it all together with `%>%`.

```
library(tidyr); library(dplyr)

df %>%   
    gather(event, date, -id) %>%   
    arrange(id) %>%   
    filter(!is.na(date))
```

which results in

```
    id  event   date
1  id1  start  date1
2  id1   mid1  date2
3  id1   mid2  date3
4  id1 finish  date4
5  id2  start  date5
6  id2   mid1  date6
7  id2 finish  date7
8  id3  start  date8
9  id3   mid1  date9
10 id3   mid2 date10
11 id3 finish date11
```

Answer (score 1):

For variety's sake, you can do the following in base R:

```
cbind(df[1], stack(lapply(df[-1], as.character)), row.names = NULL)
#     id values    ind
# 1  id1  date1  start
# 2  id2  date5  start
# 3  id3  date8  start
# 4  id1  date2   mid1
# 5  id2  date6   mid1
# 6  id3  date9   mid1
# 7  id1  date3   mid2
# 8  id2   <NA>   mid2
# 9  id3 date10   mid2
# 10 id1  date4 finish
# 11 id2  date7 finish
# 12 id3 date11 finish
```

You can wrap it in `na.omit` if you want to get rid of that `NA` and use `order` to get the data in the row order that you want.

Comment: Thanks! I was wondering whether there was an apply-way of doing it... nice to see there is!

Comment: @ElinaJ, that isn't really an apply-way.  `lapply` was just required because of how you created your data frame. `stack` doesn't work with factors.